# How to filter with default option "All"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have added default option "All" in the filter drop-down to show all results but when I filter with some Group name and then try filtering using "All" no results are shown. How Can I show all results on select of all option?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" class="input-control width-100" />

<select ng-model="group" ng-options="gp.groupID as gp.groupName for gp in groups" class="input-control width-100"><option value="" selected>All</option></select>

    <table id="tbl-holidaylist" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <th width="40%">Type</th>
            <th width="40%">Group</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="tp in types |filter:{'groupID':group}|filter:search">
                <td>{{ tp.ExpenseTypeName }}</td>
                <td>{{ tp.ExpenseGroupName }}</td
            </tr> 
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I think you should rather clear the filter than trying to filter "all".

Comment: Show the code where you incorporate `All`.

Comment: <select ng-model="group" ng-options="gp.groupID as gp.groupName for gp in groups" class="input-control width-100"><option value="" selected>All</option></select>

Comment: somehow it was not updated properly..Now you can see full code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created your app and here is the [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/uslperera/6d6bx76m/33/)

```
<tr ng-repeat="tp in types |filter:(group && {'groupID':group})|filter:search">
```

The problem is that when All is selected group becomes undefined which causes the filter to not work

Comment: @user2866086 Is this what you wanted

Comment: yes.. but not sure why the same thing is not working in my code:(

Comment: Could you try it in jsFiddle or plunker and share the link

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to a functionality like this

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uslperera/5g9exvj7/3/)

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="a as a for a in arr">
    <option value="">All</option>
</select>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="a in arr | filter:selected">{{a}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: somehow it was not updated properly..Now you can see full code.